# How can I add an on click event on a div with multiple element inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a div that is dynamically generated through `draggable` of `jQuery ui` the structure of the div that has been dragged to the `sortable` is something like this:

```
<div class="some-div" >
    <label class="label"> Label caption: </label>
    <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>
    <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>
    <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" class="checkbox"/>
</div>
```

**I want to put the event on the** `div` **and append an another** `div` **if the** `div` **or the element inside it is clicked.**

What I tried so far is:

```
$(function() {
     $(document).on('click', '.some-div', function( e ) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(e.target).append('another-div');
     });
});
```

But the code above also append the `another div` to the element inside the `div`.

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Note: id's must be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside the event handler will refer to the clicked `some-div` element. `e.target` will refer to the element where the click originated it might be the label or the input elements.

```
$(function() {
     $(document).on('click', '.some-div', function( e ) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).append('<div>another-div</div>');
     });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/J2Aw6/)